# Extjs: What is the correct way to use Associate Data of a model's field reference?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, foreign-key-relationship

The `Ext.data.Model` class represents the backend models. And just like in the server code, some of its fields can be of another declared model type via the `reference` property. I've found out that using a model's `getAssociatedData()` function returns an object with all those referenced fields. However they only contain the reference object's data object they are not full fledged initialized `Ext.data.Model`s, which forces a primitive object access and there is no way to use the model's configured proxies etc for loading/saving. Is this the correct/only way of using this functionality? We've also been looking for a way to add columns from referenced fields on a grid but it doesn't seem to work... I'm starting to doubt the usefulness of declaring referenced fields.

Example code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.ModelA', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'modelb',
        reference: 'MyApp.ModelB'
    }]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.ModelB', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'modelId',
        type: 'int'
    }]
});

//...
var modelA = new MyApp.ModelA().load();
var modelB = modelA.getAssociatedData().modelb; //This is the only way to access it.
var modelBId = modelB.get('modelId') //This returns undefined because the function .get doesn't exist.
var modelBId = modelB.id; //This works because it is a simple object property access.
//...
```

Comment: Try doing this `var modelB = modelA.getModelb()`

Answer (score 0):

As Chad Peruggia said, it seems that ExtJS creates special getters for `reference` fields that match the field name. Using `getAssociatedData()` returns only the primitive form of those objects (only their `data` values) but using the special getter (in my case `getModelb()`) it returns a full fledged model initialized with the given data.